# Unable to load index.html in ASP.NET Core application when using POST request - SPA Error 500

Tags: angular, post, single-page-application, openid-connect, middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core application with an Angular client-side application. I'm encountering an issue where the index.html page is not being loaded when making a POST request. Instead, I receive a 500 error with the message "The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.". The issue happen on develop and productive environment.

[image]

Here are some details:

- I have configured the UseSpa middleware in my startup.cs file as follows:

  ```
      app.UseSpa(spa =>
       {
           // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
           // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

           spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
           spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 30);


           spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
           {
               ServeUnknownFileTypes = true, // Ermöglicht das Servieren von Dateien ohne bekannten MIME-Typ
               DefaultContentType = "text/html", // Setzt den Standard-MIME-Typ auf 'text/html'
               OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
               {

                   // Überprüfen, ob die angeforderte Datei die 'index.html' ist
                   if (ctx.File.Name.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                   {
                       // Weiterleiten der Anfrage an die Angular-App
                       ctx.Context.Request.Path = "/dist/index.html";

                       // Führe hier die gewünschten Aktionen aus
                       Console.WriteLine("OnPrepareResponse - index.html");
                   }
               }
           };
       });
  ```
- The index.html file is located in the correct directory (/dist/index.html).
- The general routing is configured in this way

  ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "signin-oidc",
               template: "signin-oidc",
               defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Callback" }
           );

           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
           );
       });
   });
  ```

The strange thing is that this issue only occurs when making a POST request, while GET requests work fine. Additionally, I'm using the POST request scenario for OpenIDConnect implementation.

I've tried various solutions, including modifying the routing in both the server and client applications, but the issue persists. It seems that the server is not able to locate the index.html file when a POST request is made.

Additionally, the console output for the if-statement does not appear.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please let me know if you need any further information.